# Make ZSH autocorrect `les` to `less` and not `ls`?

Tags: zsh, autocorrection

I'd like to change this behavior:

```
❯ les file.txt
zsh: correct 'les' to 'ls' [nyae]?
```

To this:

```
❯ les file.txt
zsh: correct 'les' to 'less' [nyae]?
```

What's the simplest way to do this? I'm looking to retain the autocorrection but revise it a bit, so `alias les=less` is not the kind of solution I seek.

Comment: You will likely have to write your own function to achieve this... I doubt that the "ROI" for writing such a function is worth the effort.

Comment: I think your question has a typo in the second block: do you mean that you want zsh to `correct 'les' to 'less'`? Both blocks read the same at present.

Comment: Yup, corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set

```
CORRECT_IGNORE=ls
```

And then, auto-correct will never offer `ls` as a correction (even for `sl` for instance).

I find that if I do that, it now offers `lex` as a correction for `les`. Then I need `CORRECT_IGNORE='(ls|lex)'` in order to be offered `less` when entering `les`.

Other than that (and disabling it altogether with `set +o correct`), I'm not aware of any other way to tune the auto-corrector.

If you find yourself typing `les` in place of `less` often, you can always add a `alias les=less`.